# convert arrays in dictionary into list of arrays

Tags: python, list, dictionary, valueerror, conv-neural-network

I have a dictionary with name 'voltage' with 206 items in it as shown in the image. Each item is an array of (25;3;1). I want to convert the dictionary into a list of arrays and give it as input to train the model using model.fit()

[image: Dictionary]

[image: Shape of items in the dictionary]

I tried giving a 'dictionary with arrays'(voltage) as input to the model. But it gives the following error.

```
model.fit(x=voltage, y=output, steps_per_epoch=None, epochs=1000)

ValueError: No data provided for "input_1". Need data for each key in: ['input_1']
```

Later I tried converting the 'dictionary with arrays' into a 'list of arrays'

```
temp = []
input= []

for key, value in voltage:
temp = [key,value]
input.append(temp)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-8b0eb6392467> in <module>
  2 input= []
  3 
----> 4 for key, value in voltage:
  5     temp = [key,value]
  6     input.append(temp)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

I tried this but got a value error.

Please help me with this.

Thank you :)

**EDITED**
As Geethesh said, I tried this code and it has converted my dictionary into a list of arrays but the shape was weird. Initially, items in my dictionary were of the shape (25,3,1)

```
for value, key in voltage.items():
temp = [key,value]
input.append(temp)

np.shape(input)

This gives me a shape of (1, 206, 2)
```

But I need the shape of (206, 25, 3, 1). List with 206 samples, each of size (25,3,1).

How do I change the shape of the list ??

Comment: `for key, value in voltage:` should be `for key, value in voltage.items():`

Comment: Can you post your expected output in a code block? just a few lines, perhaps showing two different keys

Comment: @RichieV .Hi. I have edited the question. Please check and let me know if it is clear to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use

```
for value, key in voltage.items():
    input.append(value)
```

You can also use list comprehension

```
input= [value for value, key in  voltage.items()]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.Your suggestion has worked to help me convert the dictionary into a list of arrays.Now I would like to change the shape of all the arrays in the list to (25;3;1).I need this shape to give it as input to the model. ValueError:Error when checking input: expected input_4 to have 4 dimensions,but got array with shape (2, 1).It gives me this error if I pass the list of arrays without changing the shape. But before converting into list, all arrays in dictionary were in shape ( 25;3;1)